# Why the Content provider starting first instead of Launcher activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-lifecycle

I am working on a project and when I was debugging the code, I found that the Custom content provider is starting first instead of Application class or the starting activity. I have checked all the code we are not calling the provider in the starting activity or the Application class. So I am confused, why it is doing like this, or I am missing something, I am attaching the debug trace image. if anybody have any idea please help me. Thanks[image: Debug image]

Answer (score 2):

Your registered `ContentProviders`, along with your `Application` singleton, are created when the process starts up, no matter what is causing the process to start up. So, if the user tapped on your home screen launcher icon, your providers and `Application` will be created first, then your activity will be created.

IOW, what you are seeing is perfectly normal.